# current member from a custom set

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube, mondrian

I'm trying to create a custom set and I wanna take the current member of this custom set that I created

```
    WITH 
    SET [~SET] AS 
        Order(
            [especialidade].[nome].Members,
            [Measures].[consulta_valor],
            DESC
        )
    MEMBER [Measures].[prev] AS 
         ([especialidade].[id].CurrentMember.PREVMEMBER, [Measures].[consulta_valor])

SELECT  {[Measures].[prev],[Measures].[consulta_valor]} ON 0,
[~SET] on 1
FROM [consulta]
```

My idea is when I'm creating that member use the set that I created to do my interaction, my goal is to see if the measure of the current member is equals to the previous member because I'll put a position in my members and the same values need to have same position.
Someone could help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try
[especialidade].[nome].currentmember

The set name is just an alias. You are still referencing the nome hierarchy.

Comment: Hey, sorry I solve my problem with `[~SET].Item([~SET].CurrentOrdinal)`